# How to change default perl installation to the one installed by macports

Tags: perl, macports

I installed perl5.14 via macports.

By typing

```
which perl
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/perl
```

How do I change the perl to point the macports one.

My .profile is:

```
    # MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-02-02_at_14:42:32: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Comment: Should work what does `ls -l /opt/local.bin/perl*` show?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the perl port isn't active? try:

```
$ sudo port activate perl5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo port install perl5 +perl5_14
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to re-launch terminal for the `export` to take effect. As a quick but messy workaround you can always invoke perl like this:
`/opt/local/bin/perl` Remember to put that in your Perl scripts as well. Also, unlike unix I find I always have to use `sudo` when installing to a local directory.

Macports is great for installing all those non-Perl libraries that aren't installed on the Mac, however it is not so great for installing Perl modules as it is dependant on there being a port of it, you can't really use CPAN to install. `perlbrew` does work on the Mac and is a much better solution. But if you still want to use Macports to install non-Perl libraries you hit a problem. I solved it with a `.profile` like this:

```
source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc
# export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

Note the comment. The first line gives me my perlbrew Perl when I open terminal. When I want to use Macports to install libraries I swap the comment around and re-launch terminal and I then have Macports Perl. Of course this means I need two Perls on my machine, and they both need to be the same version but I don't have any problems with this.

Comment: I put the following workaround in my ~/.profile and afaict this enables MacPorts Perl to use modules installed with CPAN: `export PERL5LIB="/Library/Perl/5.16/"` You should replace "/Library/Perl/5.16/" with the path CPAN is using to install modules on *your* machine. YMMV but I've been doing this for years.

Answer (score 0):

Not being on a Mac, I cannot answer your exact question. However, many Perl users/developers now use `perlbrew` to install newer versions of Perl and manage choosing between them. I am fairly confident that it works on Mac. Read more at the [website](http://perlbrew.pl/) or [CPAN](http://p3rl.org/perlbrew).